# I can't copy "Appdata" to a external disc

Tags: windows-7, backup, file-transfer, external-drive

So I'm doing a backup, manually. I copied some folders in wich there is all my files (I only save things inside them). Now I want to save application data. So in case I lost the programs, I can reintall them and with the appdata restore the settings of those programs (I will not backup the installed programs). I have considered two options for doing this:
1) Back up all "Users" folder
2) Back up "Appdata" folder (wich is inside Users folder)

I want to know two things: if these are reasonable back up strategies, and the second important thing:
The appdata folder doesn't get copied. It takes too much time it doesn't seem like the process of copyng to the external drive is normal. I think the fact that is a hidden folder may have to do. It seems like it's trying to copy the same thing over and over (thought this is probably my imagination). It remained 10 minutes or more in a loop where it said there was 0% remaining, 0 bytes remaining to copy, thought it couldn't finish. Also, the folder it's 5 GB size, but when copying it says in the dialog only 236 MB. With other folders there was a blue bar that filled at the rythm the copying process was in progress, but in this case there is no blue bar. What could be the problem? Is appdata constantly changing so that it can't be copied (this can also be completely wrong, only a hipothesis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find good advice [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30173/what-files-should-you-backup-on-your-windows-pc/).
Also - you need to understand that the %APPDATA% folder might be in use by several programs so you might not be able to copy it manually at times.

**UPDATE:**
Windows can backup the APPDATA folder on its own using:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Backup and Restore --> Set Up Backup
Then choose "Manual" and choose the folders you require including APPDATA.

Comment: That's similar to what I was thinking (I thought the folder were changing with time).

Comment: That's the website I was doing the back up with. The problem is that it tells me to copy the entire Users folder, but already that folder contains appdata, wich can't really be copied because the problem I'm having. Althought, I managed to copy apppdata yesterday.

Comment: You can use internal windows backup for this folder

Comment: In automatic mode? Or do I manually select the users folder? The problem is that in automatic mode I suspect it will copy all the hard drive stupidly, and in the other mode it's manual so I don't know what folders to choose... do you say manual back up with users folder will suffice? I already copied my documents, file music, books etc. I need to copy applications data.

Comment: @Santropedro see my update. you can select to include APPDATA

Comment: Ok. I finally let windows do the automatic back up by itself. But that seems ok also.